# Assign False and '' to javascript variables from c#

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I pass model with default values (Id = 0, CityId = null, IsPublished = false) from controller to view:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? CityId { get; set; }
    public bool IsPublished { get; set; }
}
```

And in view I assign values from model to variables in javascript - cityId should be in javascript type of bool and isPublished should be in javascript null or type of int:

```
<script>    
    var cityId = @Model.CityId; // value: False
    var isPublished = @Model.IsPublished; // value: ''
</script>
```

But I have errors:

- For cityId: `Uncaught ReferenceError: False is not defined`
- For isPublished: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;`

What should I do ?

Comment: Have you checked what the actual output in the HTML is? For starters C# coerces `false` to `'False'`, so you'll have an issue with case sensitivity there

Comment: `var cityId = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.CityId))` (ditto for `IsPublished`)

Comment: Are you sure your `bool` IsPublished is giving `''`?  And your `int` CityId giving 'False' ?

Comment: @Stephen Muecke thx - it works :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Json.Encode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.json.encode%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) Method converts a data object to a string that is in the JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) format.

```
var settings = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))
```

Then it can used like

```
var cityId = settings.CityId; 
var isPublished = settings.IsPublished;
```

Answer (score 3):

For the boolean, always lowercase it:

```
var isPublished = @Model.IsPublished.ToString().ToLowerInvariant();
```

For the nullable, check it has a value and give javascript something by default:

```
var cityId = @Model.CityId ?? "null";
```

Comment: var cityId = @Model.CityId ?? "null"; - it doesn't work :(

Comment: @MrChudz care to elaborate? You get any error message?

Answer (score 0):

It's because your code is implicitly execute with `ToString`.

So C# `bool.ToString()` returns either `True` or `False`.

In Javascript, it's lowercase: `true` or `false`.

So you have to write it like this:

```
<script>    
    var cityId = @Model.CityId; // value: False
    var isPublished = @Model.IsPublished.ToString().ToLower(); // value: ''
</script>
```